# prediction plot with intervals

Tags: r, plot, prediction

I was attempting to create a prediction interval that includes the prediction for my model ( negative binomial). The model is :

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = TOT.N ~ D.PARK + OPEN.L + L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD), 
    init.theta = 4.979895131, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-3.08218  -0.70494  -0.09268   0.55575   1.67860  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     4.032e+00  3.363e-01  11.989  < 2e-16 ***
D.PARK         -1.154e-04  1.061e-05 -10.878  < 2e-16 ***
OPEN.L         -1.085e-02  3.122e-03  -3.475  0.00051 ***
L.WAT.C         1.597e-01  7.852e-02   2.034  0.04195 *  
sqrt(L.P.ROAD)  4.924e-01  3.101e-01   1.588  0.11231    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(4.9799) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 197.574  on 51  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  51.329  on 47  degrees of freedom
AIC: 383.54

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
```

I have firslt created an observed vs. predicted plot (below). From this plot i would say that the predicted data seems to fit well the actual data.

[image]

Then i am attempting to make prediction plot with condifence intervals. For this i have decided to let the variable `OPEN.L` to vary, while other variables are kept constant - on their mean. The code I have used is the following:

```
  varying OPEN.L
  minOPEN.L <- min(OPEN.L)
  maxOPEN.L <- max(OPEN.L)
  grid <- seq(minOPEN.L, maxOPEN.L, 1)
  mean.D.PARK <- mean(D.PARK)

  new <- data.frame(D.PARK = mean.D.PARK, OPEN.L = grid, L.WAT.C = mean.L.WAT.C, L.P.ROAD = mean.L.P.ROAD)

  confidece.kills <- predict(final.model, new, se = T, interval = "confidence")
  predict.kills <- predict(final.model, new, se = T, interval = "prediction")

  par(mfrow=c(1, 2), pty="m")
  matplot(grid, predict.kills$fit ,lty=c(1,2,2),type="l",lwd=3,
          xlab="OPEN.L",ylab="TOT.N",
          cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.3)
```

There is nothing to see on the plot (below):

[image]

dput(head(road.data, 55))

```
    dput(head(road.data, 55))
structure(list(TOT.N = c(22L, 14L, 65L, 55L, 88L, 104L, 49L, 
66L, 26L, 47L, 35L, 55L, 44L, 30L, 33L, 29L, 34L, 64L, 76L, 32L, 
34L, 32L, 35L, 22L, 34L, 25L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 7L, 17L, 10L, 
3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 14L, 
10L, 4L, 11L, 3L), OPEN.L = c(22.684, 24.657, 30.121, 50.277, 
43.609, 31.385, 24.81, 56.228, 48.735, 15.633, 9.999, 39.942, 
10.382, 2.507, 0.738, 15.725, 43.866, 45.102, 39.46, 19.988, 
13.369, 6.848, 2.946, 3.219, 3.218, 34.168, 22.839, 7.258, 8.513, 
23.394, 26.945, 71.436, 62.203, 82.391, 97.574, 94.947, 89.294, 
68.779, 62.173, 67.834, 67.618, 83.357, 70.684, 30.907, 26.687, 
9.571, 26.687, 16.478, 26.365, 39.609, 33.511, 24.438), MONT.S = c(0, 
0, 0.258, 1.783, 2.431, 0, 0, 0, 1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 5.235, 3.658, 5.049, 0.224, 9.426, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.763, 
7.134, 0, 0, 1.039, 4.326, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.455, 0, 0, 
0, 4.347, 0, 1.376, 4.347, 1.796, 0, 0.259), POLIC = c(4.811, 
2.224, 1.946, 0.625, 0.791, 0.054, 0.022, 11.263, 1.238, 0.119, 
0.024, 0, 0.038, 0, 0, 0, 0.06, 0.125, 1.7, 0, 0.308, 0.364, 
0.013, 0, 0, 0, 0.529, 0.313, 0.063, 0.202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.206, 
0.259, 0.278, 0.812, 0.03, 0.018, 0.206, 0.375, 0.086, 0.05, 
0.06, 0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.044, 1.861, 0.151), D.PARK = c(250.214, 
741.179, 1240.08, 1739.885, 2232.13, 2724.089, 3215.511, 3709.401, 
4206.477, 4704.176, 5202.328, 5700.669, 6199.342, 6698.151, 7187.762, 
7668.833, 8152.155, 8633.224, 9101.411, 9573.578, 10047.63, 10523.939, 
11002.496, 11482.896, 11976.232, 12470.968, 12968.285, 13465.914, 
13961.321, 14432.954, 14904.995, 15377.983, 15854.389, 16335.936, 
16810.109, 17235.045, 17673.064, 18167.269, 18656.949, 19149.507, 
19645.717, 20141.987, 20640.729, 21138.903, 21631.542, 22119.102, 
22613.647, 23113.45, 23606.088, 24046.886, 24444.874, 24884.803
), SHRUB = c(0.406, 0.735, 0.474, 0.607, 0.173, 0.325, 0.055, 
0.092, 1.744, 0, 0.67, 0.783, 0, 0.178, 0, 0, 0.094, 0.107, 0.702, 
0.827, 1.025, 0, 0.01, 0.012, 0.088, 0.02, 0.087, 0.116, 0.062, 
0, 0, 0.033, 0.133, 0.047, 0.077, 0.182, 0.067, 0.208, 0.063, 
0.122, 0.038, 0.095, 0, 0.02, 0.064, 0.137, 0.064, 0.214, 0.14, 
0.622, 0, 0.18), WAT.RES = c(0.043, 0.182, 0.453, 0.026, 0, 0.039, 
0.114, 0.224, 0.177, 0, 6.309, 2.26, 0.137, 0, 0, 0.402, 0.077, 
0.042, 0, 0.479, 0.36, 0, 0.078, 0, 0, 0, 0.188, 0, 0, 0, 0.213, 
2.452, 0.061, 0, 0, 0, 0.284, 0.579, 0.215, 0, 0, 0, 0.127, 0, 
0.198, 0.473, 0.198, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.319), L.WAT.C = c(583, 1419, 
2005, 1924, 2167, 2391, 1165, 2428, 2416, 211, 292, 650, 1896, 
2194, 1375, 0, 1655, 1702, 2721, 1694, 1192, 589, 476, 345, 1621, 
1023, 357, 0, 0, 7, 878, 883, 1921, 1479, 1237, 1898, 3951, 1931, 
1365, 591, 868, 1198, 2334, 3525, 3087, 2444, 3087, 3934, 2214, 
2122, 1290, 2471), L.P.ROAD = c(1975, 1761, 1250, 666, 653, 1309, 
685, 677, 664, 654, 696, 678, 652, 665, 655, 627, 1159, 2201, 
2290, 1617, 866, 640, 620, 645, 853, 1370, 631, 603, 609, 605, 
1374, 685, 594, 1075, 595, 676, 684, 733, 1739, 891, 730, 652, 
668, 645, 602, 571, 602, 953, 765, 1578, 2960, 1407), D.WAT.COUR = c(735, 
134.052, 269.029, 48.751, 126.102, 344.444, 95.133, 243.23, 187.084, 
236.004, 15.184, 118.865, 332.257, 28.498, 168.818, 560, 104.839, 
204.943, 256.812, 566.152, 689.823, 694, 300, 132.934, 253.305, 
34.119, 515.233, 825, 1165, 1025, 754.938, 585, 137.112, 80.916, 
35.426, 43, 31.01, 290.029, 68.496, 405, 785, 257, 118.579, 237.041, 
45.832, 44.744, 120.855, 24.313, 178.837, 21.336, 111.764, 225.514
)), .Names = c("TOT.N", "OPEN.L", "MONT.S", "POLIC", "D.PARK", 
"SHRUB", "WAT.RES", "L.WAT.C", "L.P.ROAD", "D.WAT.COUR"), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**How can i obtain the prediction plot with the corresponding prediction intervals?**

any input - comments, constructive critique, tipps - is appriciated. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can approximate the interval yourself like this:

```
attach(road.data)
library("MASS")
final.model <- glm.nb(formula = TOT.N ~ D.PARK + OPEN.L + L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD),
       init.theta = 4.979895131, link = log)

minOPEN.L <- min(OPEN.L)
maxOPEN.L <- max(OPEN.L)
grid <- seq(minOPEN.L, maxOPEN.L, 1)
mean.D.PARK <- mean(D.PARK)
mean.L.WAT.C <- mean(L.WAT.C)
mean.L.P.ROAD <- mean(L.P.ROAD)

new <- data.frame(D.PARK = mean.D.PARK, OPEN.L = grid, L.WAT.C = mean.L.WAT.C, L.P.ROAD = mean.L.P.ROAD)

predict.kills <- predict(final.model, new, se = T, interval = "prediction")

alpha <- 0.05 ## you want a 95% interval
z <- qnorm(1 - alpha / 2)
lower <- predict.kills$fit - z * predict.kills$se.fit
upper <- predict.kills$fit + z * predict.kills$se.fit

par(mfrow=c(1, 2), pty="m")
matplot(grid, cbind(predict.kills$fit, lower, upper) ,lty=c(1,2,2),type="l",lwd=3,
        xlab="OPEN.L",ylab="log(TOT.N)",
        cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.3)

matplot(grid, exp(cbind(predict.kills$fit, lower, upper)) ,lty=c(1,2,2),type="l",lwd=3,
        xlab="OPEN.L",ylab="TOT.N",
        cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.3)
```

And you will get your result like this:

[image]

Comment: @ consistency, thank you for your help. I have previously calculated the condifence intervals (in my case they should be a little more narrow than yours, as i am fitting a negative binomial model):`                    Estimate         2.5 %        97.5 %
(Intercept)     4.0319970271  3.4094551079  4.655064e+00
D.PARK         -0.0001153607 -0.0001365551 -9.456738e-05
OPEN.L         -0.0108517031 -0.0170224260 -4.715599e-03
L.WAT.C         0.1597156504  0.0042580137  3.162945e-01
sqrt(L.P.ROAD)  0.4923973866 -0.0876563360  1.092080e+00` . How can i theseinsted of the `lower` \ `upper`?

Comment: init.theta = 4.979895131 stand for the overdispersion constant right? what does it do exactly?

Comment: @Danka So you already calculate the 95% intervals for all of the coefficients' estimation and you want to use these intervals to get 95% interval for your response? To my knowledge, there is no easy way to do this. Either you can just combine the result of these 95% intervals to get your final 95% interval, but that will be too wide; either you need to know the relationship between these predictors.

Comment: @Danka I think theta is the overdispersion parameter, if it is not, it is closely related to the overdispersion parameter. Overdispersion is, if you use `glm` models, there will be some relationship between the mean and variance (in Poisson case, mean equals variance), but that may not be the case and what we want, so we use overdispersion parameter to deal with that, back again to Poisson example, we may let variance = theta * mean, and theta will be the overdispersion parameter.

Comment: why have you chosen theta to be 4.979895131 then?

Comment: @Danka This is only some initial value for theta used for the numerical algorithm in `glm.nb`, it is not the final estimated value for theta. The initial value affects the results, but not that much. In this case, whether set initial theta to 1 or 2 or 5 obtain similar results around theta = 4.97......

Comment: Caution: `predict.glm()` doesn't have an `interval =` argument that can be set to `"prediction"`, the way `predict.lm()` does. From my understanding, this means that that piece of code will be ignored, and the interval generated will be a 95% CI around the mean.